# Как полосу прокрутки установить выше фиксированного блока

Tags: html, css, fixed, overflow

У меня проблема заключается в том, что слева находится дополнительный блок тоже с фиксированной частью и прокруткой, поэтому если установить обычное поведение прокрутки для правой стороны (которое как раз-таки поможет отрисовать прокрутку выше фиксированного блока), то тогда будут прокручиваться сразу две стороны. Так же z-index не помогает.

```css
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #main {
            width: 300px;
            border: solid 1px;
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }

        .fixed {
            background-color: grey;
            height: 50px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 283px;
        }

        li {
            height: 50px;
            border-bottom: solid 1px;
        }

        li:first-of-type {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .infinityBlock {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .leftColumn {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100vh
        }
        .second{
            width:100%;
        }
        .rightColumn{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="fixed">
            Radio
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="leftColumn">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>10</li>
                <li>11</li>
                <li>12</li>
                <li>13</li>
                <li>14</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="fixed infinityBlock">
            Radio 222
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="rightColumn">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>10</li>
                <li>11</li>
                <li>12</li>
                <li>13</li>
                <li>14</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `position: fixed` позиционирует элемент относительно окна браузера, что и приводит к проблемам, с которыми Вы столкнулись. В Вашем случае лучше использовать `position: sticky` (правда, он в IE не поддерживается)

И структура разметки у Вас очень сложная.

Может так получше будет?

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/pozZjwg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item--title {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul class="column">
    <li class="item item--title">TITLE</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="column">
    <li class="item item--title">TITLE</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
    <li class="item">lorem</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```